# Move image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong with this function?

```
function moveColor()
 {
 document.getElementById(purple).style.marginRight = "34px";
 }
```

with this html:

```
<div><img src="images/purple.png" id="purple" onclick="colorpurple()" onmouseover="moveColor()" style="cursor:pointer;"/></div>
```

I also wanted to have it move over a period of 1 second, but can't seem to solve this simple problem.

Comment: you might want to look into jquery `animate` function http://api.jquery.com/animate/ (there is sample code in the middle of the page)

Comment: What does "wanted to have it move over a period of 1 second" mean? You want it to slide over? You can use [CSS3 transforms](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/) for that or [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do it easily.

Comment: I also suggest jQuery, all you'd have to do is: `$('#purple').animate({'margin-right':'34px'},1000)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the id in quotes (*so that it is treated as a string*).

```
document.getElementById('purple').style.marginRight = "34px";
```

The current usage means that `purple` refers to a variable, which is not defined so it has an `undefined` value and so the `document.getElementById` method returns nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed the quotes on the function getElementById.

Like this:

```
function moveColor() { 
      document.getElementById('purple').style.marginRight = "34px";
}
```